# Algebraic closure of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})(T)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Is there a concrete description of the algebraic closure of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})(T)$?

Comment: Is $T$ an indeterminate?

Comment: Yes, I mean that this field is the fraction field of the polynomial ring in one variable $T$.

Comment: An interesting but very, very difficult question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First notice that the required algebraic closure must contain an algebraic closure $\overline { \mathbb F_p}$ of $\mathbb F_p$, so that we must actually find an algebraic closure of $\overline { \mathbb F_p}(t)$.

For an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic zero (like $\mathbb C$) an algebraic closure of $k(T)$ is the algebraic closure of  $k(T)$ in the algebraically closed field of Puiseux series $$k((T^{\frac{1}{\infty}}))=\bigcup_{n\geq 1} k((T^{\frac{1} 
{n}}))$$

This is no longer true if $char. k\gt 0$, as Chevalley showed by exhibiting as a counterexample the polynomial $Y^p-Y-T^{-1}\in k(T)[Y]$, which has  no root in $k((T^{\frac{1}{\infty}}))$.

Fortunately   a modification of the notion of Puiseux series gives an analogue in characteristic $p$ of the above algebraic closedness result and that should, in principle, solve your problem.
 You could consult [Kedlaya's paper](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=39&cad=rja&ved=0CG4QFjAIOB4&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fproc%2F2001-129-12%2FS0002-9939-01-06001-4%2FS0002-9939-01-06001-4.pdf&ei=oCV8UeakMYfAO939gYAN&usg=AFQjCNGjx-h7I0T58wj9vDYDvOfEn8eN5g&bvm=bv.45645796,d.ZWU) for details.

Comment: But is there a concrete description of the $\overline{k}(T)$-algebraic elements inside the field of Puiseux series?

Comment: @Ted: no, I don't believe there is such a description. As an analogy, can you think of a description of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ in  $\mathbb C$ that wouldn't amount to the definition?